# How to locating TLD with fallback mechanism when URI does not map any entries?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, tags, java-ee-6, tld

The taglib map mantained by the container (URI <-> TLD location)

1st. Look at deployment descriptor (web.xml) TLD-to-URI

2nd. Implicit map entries  element of TLD

3rd. Implicit map entries from container

After that how does it work if URI used in taglib directive does not map any entries?

Answer (score 0):

> By Frits Walraven 
>   **From JSP specs** 
>   The fallback interpretation is targetted to a casual use of the mechanism, as in the development cycle of theWeb
>   Application; in that case the URI is interpreted as a direct path to
>   the TLD
>   ...
>   the fallback rule allows a taglib directive to refer
>   directly to the TLD. This arrangement is very convenient for quick
>   development at the expense of less flexibility and accountability.

For example:

```
<%@ taglib uri='/WEB-INF/tlds/PRlibrary_1_4.tld' prefix="x" %>
```